# Spherical curve with constant torsion.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let $\alpha :I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a spherical curve, regular, with $\alpha ''(s)\neq 0$  and with constant torsion $\tau_0$. Let $r=\frac{1}{k}$ where $k$ is the curvature of $\alpha$. Show that $r''=-\tau_0^2r$.

What I have tried to do is this: derivating (several times) the expression $<\alpha(s)-p,\alpha(s)-p>=a^2$, where $p$ is the centre of the sphere that containd the curve and $a$ is its radius. However, I haven't been able to reach a conclusion.

Any tips?

Comment: Let's see your explicit work. You need to use the Frenet equations and you need to use the fact that $\vec T,\vec N,\vec B$ form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$. Oh, and you definitely want to assume $s$ is arclength, even though you didn't say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote the Frenet frame of $\alpha$ by $\{T,N,B\}$. As you say, let's differentiate the equality
$$
(\alpha-p)\cdot(\alpha-p)=a^{2},
$$
which gives
$$
T\cdot\alpha=0.\tag{1}
$$
Differentiating once more and using the Frenet equations, we get
$$
kN\cdot\alpha+1=0 \Rightarrow r=\frac{1}{k}=-N\cdot\alpha.\tag{2}
$$
Then
$$
r'=-N'\cdot\alpha-N\cdot T=(kT-\tau_{0}B)\cdot\alpha=-\tau_{0}B\cdot\alpha,
$$
using (1) in the last equality. Differentiate once more:
$$
r''=-\tau_{0}(-\tau_{0}N\cdot\alpha+B\cdot T)=\tau_{0}^{2}N\cdot\alpha=-\tau_{0}^{2}r,
$$
using (2) in the last equality.